# Parse XML and Re-write the Filename Using an XML Element

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to parse an XML and re-name the original XML using one of its child elements, specifically as a prefix for the filename of an XML to be overwritten. In the sample XML below, I want to extract the "to" element and insert its name "Tove" into a newly written XML filename. If the original file was named "reminder.xml", could the name "Tove" be parsed and inserted into a newly written file called "Tove_reminder.xml"?  Is this possible with XMLs?

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
-<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>`
```

It seems that Python has more flexibility extracting text and strings in other file formats, but I cannot find much that pertains to XML.  Any help is most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use beautifulsoup4 to extract attribute and inner texts of an xml document.

first, install beautfulsoup4

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Then, assuming the text you wrote in your question is loaded in a variable named xml_text, you can do the following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file_name = "reminder.xml"
xml_file = open(file_name, 'r')
xml_text = xml_file.read()
xml_file.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_text, "html.parser")
```

To extract a text from a tag, you can then use

```
to = soup.find("to")
name = to.text #contains Tove now
```

Finally, you can use the "name" variable to save the file

```
file_name = name + "_" + file_name

xml_file = open(file_name, "w")
xml_file.write(xml_text)
xml_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, Hussein!  This is definitely helpful, I was able to replicate the above with no errors but if possible I would like to do this via a path/filename (e.g. with open("<path_to_xml>", "r") as file:) to then pull the tag name and overwrite as a new XML.  I have been trying to do so using the elementTree library but not successfully... if there is an easier way via BeautifulSoup that would be awesome - Thanks again for your help! :D

Comment: Hello @mdl518, I edited the answer for you to save the file. please mark it as the correct answer so others can find it as well

Comment: Hey, @Hussein, your helpful edits look like they largely did the trick but the only issue is that the name (Tove) was prefixed before the full path name.  When I run the code above, I get the following error - "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Tove_C:\\Users\\Mark_D\\Desktop\\reminder.xml'".  I think we may need to add a line to point to the path of the filename instead (e.g. "os.listdir(<location_of_xml>)")  and append "Tove" in front of "reminder" while preserving the output directory path.  If you are able to assist it would be most helpful, and will gladly mark as the correct answer!

Comment: Ideally, I need the newly written file to have the path "C:\\Users\\Mark_D\\Desktop\\Tove_remainder.xml".  I would assume I could extract other tags using the soup.find method as well and also insert into the output XML as appropriate - Thanks for your continued assistance!!

Comment: @ Hussein - I now have the solution for pointing to an XML in a directory: 

`path="C:\\Users\\Mark_D\\Desktop\\"
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xml")): with open(filename) as open_file: content = open_file.read() soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser") # extract text from a tag to = soup.find("to") name = to.text #contains Tove now filename = os.path.join(path, name + ".xml") with open(filename,'w') as f: f.write(content) f.close()`

Many thanks for helping point me in the right direction!